# Scripted GitHub setup for private repos on new EC2 instance?

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2, github-api

Basically, I'm trying to clone private repos (and gists) on a new EC2 instance within a user-data-file.  Currently (post instance launch), I generate a key, add it to my GitHub account, then clone the repos (and manually enter github password).  Should I use something ike gitosis for this?  There must be a better way!

```
# Setup GitHub keys at /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa

    sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa -C $GIT_EMAIL
```

...cp id_rsa.pub into account

```
git clone repo
```

Answer (score 3):

You should define a password-less [deploy key](http://help.github.com/deploy-keys/).

I'd automate the rest as follows:

1. Your `user-data` contains the deploy key.
2. The deploy-key is setup (this is a matter of copying to your home dir).
3. Run your checkout.

If it doesn't fit within the `user-data`, I'd suggest to write a script to do it for you (and fetch the script in `user-data` and then run it -- the easiest way to get around the space constraint).

Another suggestion would be to use something like [chef-solo](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) or [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) and leverage their deploy resources. They take a lot of extra work off your hands.